# AWS Neptune access from Lambda - Error 429 "Too Many Requests"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am working on an app that uses AWS Lambda which eventually updates Neptune.
I noticed, that in some cases I get a 429 Error from Neptune: Too Many Requests.
Well, as descriptive as it might sound, I would love to hear an advice on how to deal with it.
What would be the best way to handle that?

Although I am using a dead letter queue, I'd rather have it not going this road at the first place.

Btw the lambda is triggered by a SQS (standard) queue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you certain that the 429 error is coming from Neptune (on issue of a Gremlin or SPARQL query) or is it coming from the invocation of your Lambda function?

Comment: Definitely coming from Neptune.   I'm having the same error here, it is even preventing queries from notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely run into the WebSocket connection limit.
The Javascript client of Gremlin is not managing a connection pool. The documentation recommends using a single connection per Lambda lifetime and manually handling retry. (If the gremlin client doesn't do it for you).

[Neptune Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/limits.html)

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions.html#lambda-functions-websocket-connections)